# how can we get image from header folder to my own theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i create wordpress theme from scratch, all function is run very well, but i have 2 css and 2 javascript function, and i want to display image in my banner div, than how can display image on banner div and banner image is in header folder and javascript is in lib folder, please help me i am new to wordpress.
So pls tell me how to get custom image in banner.

```
 <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
           <?php $header_image = get_header_image();
    if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="nivoSlider" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
     <script src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?  >/lib/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>/lib/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use the Nivo Slider plugin and just implement the shortcode into the theme. That way you can use the inbuilt admin panel to help you along.

There are a few ways of doing this.

First, download Nivo Slider for wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/nivo-slider-for-wordpress/

(or search for it inside install plugins).

Place this in your theme where you want the slider:

```
<?php if (function_exists('nivoslider4wp_show')) { nivoslider4wp_show(); } ?>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any plugin, in my html templete there is jquery in built banner in header section, i just want to use that jquery and css for wordpress header, i useed wp_enqueue_script() function.